# UIWebView supported tags

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I can't find a list of supported tags for UIWebView.

If I use

```
-(void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

method, does it have any tag limitations?

Comment: refer it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: A `UIWebView` is based on WebKit just like Safari. You can show just about any website on the Internet in a web view.

Comment: @James I read this. didn't find these limits.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't need to show a website, I need to load html string. and want to know whether UIWebView has some limitations or not.

Comment: My point was that if `UIWebView` can show any site on the Internet, it can handle any valid HTML you want to pass to `loadTHMLString...`. Just remember that like with any HTML content, you need to test the end result to be sure it renders as expected.

Comment: @James can you quote the answer to my question?

Comment: @DmitryKhryukin i dot have exact answer for ur quest.. but i m sure apple library file says all..

Answer (score -1):

You can use & load your html string Note: HTML string must be proper HTML in single string. and its behavior depend on HTML. :)

```
[webviewobject loadHTMLString:@"<html><body style=\"background-color: #0646536;  font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 18pt;\"></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

To access its internal link you need to go through with

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```